# Using Axios Node.js to request an oAuth2 token - works using 'request' but not with Axios

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, axios, client, credentials

Following code works fine:

```
request({
  url: 'https://xxxxxxx/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
    user: 'clientId',
    pass: 'clientSecret'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
  console.log("Access Token:", json.access_token);
});
```

However, when I try and replicate this using Axios (as request is now deprecated) i keep getting a 401

```
axios.request({
    url: 'https://xxxxxxx/oauth/token',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
      username: 'clientId',
      password: 'clientSecret',
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    },
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);  
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error = " + err);
  });
```

i.e. catch picks up the error response 401

Any ideas on how to code the successful 'request' into axios ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `axios` sends data in JSON format. To send form data you need to use `URLSearchParams` or `qs.stringify`.

See [Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

Answer (score 5):

Solution suggested above sorted the problem.  Solution looks like:

```
const qs = require('querystring');
const data = { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'};
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  auth:{
    username: 'clientId',
    password: 'clientSecret',
  },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url: 'https://xxxxxxxxx/oauth/token',
}

axios.request(options).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);  
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("error = " + err);
    });
```